Lost with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE handling
I'm trying to get a full sized image from this action, to no avail.
private void photoIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
    }

if I do it this way, I get a RESULT_OK, and can get the thumbnail image easily like so:
  // called after camera intent finished
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PIC && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
            createDrawingView(bitmap);
        } 

but then the file seams to never be created... despite WRITE and READ authorizations ok
If I put the path as an extra, the result is allways null (RESULT_CANCELED).
Here is my manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.marzinp.mycelium"
    android:versionCode="120"
    android:versionName="1.2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/lombric"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.marzinp.mycelium.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"         
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.profileimage.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>

I've tried creating a temp file  and pass its path to the intent.
I've tried ignoring the RESULT_CODE...
Ive tried using file provider, with the same result.
I've read all answers I could about this problem, never found a solution.
I've tried 2 different real phones and 3 emulators...
I tried targeting lower versions of sdk (default is 30 in my project)
Whatever I do, the picture file is never written.
Is there a way, or do I have to use cameraX instead of camera?
Sorry I'm a rooky, and thanks for your help.

"the file seams to never be created" -- your existing code is telling the camera app that a directory is a file, which will not work. "I've tried creating a temp file and pass its path to the intent" -- that is highly unlikely to work, as the camera app may not have rights to access that path on the filesystem. "Ive tried using file provider, with the same result" -- since that is the correct solution, I suggest that you either edit this question or replace it with one that shows that implementation.

Also, please remove <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> and <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />, as you are not a camera app and those items at best will interfere with what you are trying to do. Also note that there is no permission named READ_CALENDAR_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the Android SDK. "the result is allways null" -- there is no result Uri if you use EXTRA_OUTPUT, if that is what you mean.

Note that there are hundreds of projects in GitHub that use ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, even if we limit it to Java.

Thanks for your answer. this app used to work perfectly, years ago! ANd sorry for the calendar auto completion mistake!
"there is no result Uri if you use EXTRA_OUTPUT, if that is what you mean"
I got that, but I mean that the onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) resultCode is 0

Thanks for your advice. I've been able to make it work with a provider, got read of all the authorizations, because I call device apps to do the job. I switched to sdk 35 relatively easily! It's solved!
